I need help understanding how all the subarrays are being considered in this solution
The Question:
You are given a 0-indexed integer array nums.
The distinct count of a subarray of nums is defined as:
Let nums[i..j] be a subarray of nums consisting of all the indices from i to j such that 0 <= i <= j < nums.length. Then the number of distinct values in nums[i..j] is called the distinct count of nums[i..j].
Return the sum of the squares of distinct counts of all subarrays of nums.
A subarray is a contiguous non-empty sequence of elements within an array.
This is the solution online since I wasn't able to solve it myself but I don't understand how it takes all the subarrays into consideration:
Solution:
    int sumCounts(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            unordered_map<int, int> hash;
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                hash[nums[j]]++;
                result += (hash.size() * hash.size());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

for example: [1,2,1]
it considers:[1,2,1]
then: [2,1]
and then [1]
but what about [2] and [1]?
I'm very confused where I am going wrong. Kindly help me understand it.

Have you debugged your code yet?  Side note have a look at set, or unordered_set i.o unordered_map

I wasn't able to solve it myself -- You should have developed a plan and an algorithm before writing a single line of code.  The problem of just jumping in and coding a "solution" is that you risk painting yourself into a corner, where your code doesn't work for all cases.  Then you potentially have to start all over again, just to fix the handling of those cases that fail.  A proper plan before you write any code is what you should have strived to do.

Worse, you'll often find what Paul describes above after wasting hours or days on debugging code that could never work.

Each iteration of the inner loop corresponds to one subarray.
First iteration outer loop: i == 0
First iteration inner loop: j == 0, subarray is {1}, the target value for that subarray is computed via (hash.size() * hash.size()) and accumulated in result.
Second iteration inner loop: j == 1, subarray is {1,2}, the same hashmap is used and only the last element is added. The target value is comuted the same as before and accumulated in target.
... and so on ...
On the next iteration of the outerloop the subarrays start at index i=1 and a fresh hasmap is used to keep track of the distinct elements while traversing the array to bigger subarrays.
The subarrays you are missing is:
{2}, that is the 2nd iteration of outer loop, first iteration inner loop, ie when i == 1 (start index of the subarray) and j == 1 (end index of subarray).
{1}, 3rd iteration of outer loop, first iteration inner loop.
You should use a debugger to see this.
